# Installing MySQL on Windows Vista (with IIS)

Tags: mysql, iis, windows-vista

Why is installing MySQL on Windows Vista such a bear?  For someone who is not 
a professional database administrator, it seems like I am jumping through hoops.

This page
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,200958,204223#REPLY
pointed to this page
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/archive/2008/04/04/installing-5-0-51a-mysql-community-edition-on-windows-vista.aspx
which suggests this page
http://port25.technet.com/archive/2007/03/16/mysql-on-windows-configuration-install.aspx
which points to this beautiful pdf file
http://port25.technet.com/videos/research/MySQL_Windows.pdf
Ah, now I am getting somewhere.

It suggested I turn off the User Account Control (UAC).  Which I did.

But after following these steps
There was an error at the end of the installation that said that the server failed to start.
[IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/help-1.jpg[/IMG]

Where do I go to find answers?

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer to see if it says *why* the service failed to start?

Comment: The description for Event ID 100 from source MySQL cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Aborting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revo Uninstaller did the trick at removing the registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before and while I never figured out exactly what caused the problem, it was related to previously installing/uninstalling MySQL. It seems the software does not completely remove the service registration, which then conflicts with new installations. I eventually got it fixed using the "sc" tool and deleting anything MySQL-related in the registry, followed by a reboot and re-install.

[More Information in this bug report.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45050)

Comment: What is the sc tool?
I will have to google that
I have uninstalled the program, now I guess I will dive into the registry with the regedit

Comment: MySQL is there in the list of Services.  I tried starting it and it gave an Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

Comment: I've found that MySQL starting and then stoping is often a firewall issue.  You mostly need create an exception for mysqld-nt.exe (or what ever your copy is named) and you should be off and running.

Answer (score 0):

The service was likely installed, but not started. Cancel that particular wizard and start the service manually via the services manager. Setting it to automatic will start it each time Windows is started.

Possible steps to open the services manager are along the lines of `Right-click Computer -> Manage -> Services`. The service name is set during the install and defaults to `MySQL`. I'm not near a Vista machine at the moment, or I would check this for you.

Comment: Thanks,
I did a new installation and I still got that installation error.  MySQL is there in the list of Services.  I tried starting it and it gave an Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install a stack such as

WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/

or

XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

- it installs Apache, PHP, MySQL all in one install. Takes maybe a few minutes at most. I use WAMP on Vista Business 32.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble in the past with MySQL and in attempting to uninstall it not everything is removed in Vista and Win 7. If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend uninstalling again and afterwards look in the hidden directory C:\Program Data. Delete the MySQL directory that is located there and then try reinstalling from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion from bmarstella for me. Thanks alot bmarstella :)

Please uninstall all existing MY SQL server, tools, toad etc, then remove MYSQL from Program Files, then remove MYSQL from ProgramData and from registry.

It worked for me :)